# Swivel Mount for 15.6" Portable External Monitor?

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

I've just bought a 15.6" external touch monitor (dimensions similar to Surface Book) as I'd like to carry it around occasionally. I'd like to add it to my existing desktop setup for routine use.

I'd like to add it to some sort of mount for comfort. However, given how light the monitor (~700g) is, it'd be an overkill to use a VESA adaptor. So I've been looking into adding it onto a "scissor spring arm" system instead. Most tablet mounts only go up to iPad Pro size. After much searching, I've finally found one that fits my monitor on Aliexpress (see photos).

The degrees of freedom of this mount is simply amazing. I can swing the arm around when I incline backwards on my PC chair and read comfortably.

The hinges of the scissor arm seem strong enough for the monitor. However, the swivel ball head seems to be the weak spot. It needs to be turned quite tight to feel secure. I'm worried that the current setup won't be very durable. Everything would be perfect if the ball is 30% larger. The only problem is - I can't find many options for monitors of this size.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a more stable mount with similar freedom of movement?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could keep the clamp part and see if you can attach the clamp alone to some other (vesa) mount. Might need some sort of hand made adapter, like a piece of wood and drill holes for vesa mount.